# parseFloat not working in angularjs view

Tags: angularjs

The following conditional return false inside a angular view:

```
<a ng-class="(parseFloat('-0.56%') < 0) ? 'true' : 'false'">...</a>
```

I've already added the parseFloat method in $scope.

```
$scope.parseFloat = parseFloat;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, there is no asterisks, my mistake posting the question.

Comment: What is your intended output? to have either the class `true` or `false`?

Comment: The intent is to have different classes depending if a value is bigger than zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KY5VL/3/)

You can use option 1 (as you have it) but you need to use `class` not `ng-class`

```
<a class="{{(parseFloat('-0.56%') < 0) ? 'true1' : 'false'}}">Option 1</a>
```

In order to use `ng-class` use this:

```
<a ng-class="{'true': (parseFloat('-0.56%') < 0), 'false': (parseFloat('-0.56%') >= 0)}">Option 2a</a>    
<a ng-class="{'true': (parseFloat('0.56%') < 0), 'false': (parseFloat('0.56%') >= 0)}">Option 2b</a>
```

The difference being is that `ng-class` takes an object where the `key` is the class and the `value` is the boolean evaluation to determine if the class gets added to the element.